# Rails Form not saving the Association Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For some reason, the form seems to work as intended but it does not process correctly:

Here are the parameters that are sent to my Paragraph#create method

`Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"s6V7WS6NZwcu4ZAeSenkEgVEd6MrrDD1asMjPEOuZHyglMKoGQ/5cP/USzF/5MJV3wyFn+siC2t47dSFkVtuVQ==", "paragraph"=>{"sentiments_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"body"=>"test"}}}}`

I get this error when trying to submit the form: `Sentiments body can't be blank`

```
 #paragraphs_controller.rb
  def create
    @paragraph = Paragraph.new(paragraph_params)
    @paragraph.sentiments.build
    if @paragraph.save
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      puts @paragraph.errors.full_messages
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end

  private
  def paragraph_params
    params.require(:paragraph).permit(:sentiments_attributes => [:body])
  end
```

I have 2 models, Sentiment & Paragraph. The Paragraph is a collection of sentiments. So if I have a form to create a new paragraph, it creates a sentiment at the same time.

```
class Sentiment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :paragraph, optional: true
  validates :body, presence: true

end
class Paragraph < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sentiments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :sentiments

end

<%= form_for(@paragraph) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :sentiments do |u| %>
        <%= u.text_area :body %>
  <% end  %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**UPDATED**

Need to remove `@paragraph.sentiments.build` from `paragraphs_controller#create`

Comment: Do you already get your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to remove @paragraph.sentiments.build from paragraphs_controller#create